# subclipse and subversive in parallel

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, subversive

I have to move some projects to svn 1.7, therefore I am forced to use subclipse. Can I define on project level if subversive or subversive shall be used? Or is this only definable if I create a new "checkout from svn" project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, but the problem is that it is virtually impossible to tell Subclipse and Subversive apart in the UI.  So when you use Team > Share to connect a project you will just see two SVN entries in the UI.

The best thing would be to just pick one of them and use it for all.